# async typed-rest-client and promise execution

Tags: typescript, async-await, electron

I'm very new to Typescript and developing my first Electron based application. The first part is a class that populates a local DB with results from a json web service.

My Classes to get the data are as below, an extended class. Within the getAll, if I console out the body after JSON.parse I can see my results in my console without a problem.

```js
import * as typedHttpClient from "typed-rest-client/HttpClient";

abstract class Client<Id, Item> {
  private url: string;

  constructor(url: string) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  public async getAll() {
    const httpc: typedHttpClient.HttpClient = new typedHttpClient.HttpClient("pip-dev");
    let body = await (await httpc.get(this.url)).readBody();
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    return body;
  }


}

export default Client;
```

```js
import { BASE_URI } from "../config";
import Client from "./client";

const URI = `${BASE_URI}/v2/achievements/daily`;

export interface IAchievementDaily {
  id: number;
  level: ILevel;
  required_access: string[];
}

export interface ILevel {
  min: number;
  max: number;
}

export class AchievementsDailyClient extends Client<number, IAchievementDaily> {
  constructor() {
    super(URI);
  }
}

export default new AchievementsDailyClient();
```

However, when I call this from my Database class with the following code, I only manage to get either a Promise:String or Object:Object output.

```js
  public getAchievementsDaily() {
    const response = api.achievementsDaily.getAll();
    response.then((result) => this.logInformation(result));
  }

  private logInformation(inf: any) {
    if (inf) {
     // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
     console.dir("Information : " + inf, { depth: null, colors: true });
    }
  }
```

As far as I can tell, the response.then command should only be called once my getAll has returned the body. I've checked multiple tutorials and this was as far as I could get.

I'm clearly missing something as this shouldn't be this hard. Is there something that I need to do to parse the results differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
console.dir("Information : " + inf, { depth: null, colors: true });
```

the string concatenation is calling `inf.toString()`, converting `inf` to that useless `[object Object]` string before it even gets to `console.dir`.  Try this and you may see your data:

```
console.dir("Information : ", inf, { depth: null, colors: true });
```

Comment: That just me `'Information : '`, however just inf without trying to concatenate it together works just fine. Thanks for that. Probably works as it was in the getAll because it's still a string object at that point.